# Angular service not passing form data after routing

Tags: html, angular, typescript, service, components

New to Angular and I feel like there's just an obvious mistake I am missing, code-wise.

I'm trying to follow the tutorial here: https://youtu.be/CUAHJxWGia0

I have one component to create/add an employee's ID called **CreateEmployee**.
On submission, it should route to a component to list all employees (**ListEmployees**).
It's using **employee.service.ts**.

When I click submit (before or without routing), it correctly logs the employee input to the console on CreateEmployee.
The problem is that when routing to the second component, ListEmployees, my new entry is not displayed at all, and only my test data is displayed.
I've made sure EmployeeService is included in my app.module as well.

**create-employee.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { FormControl, FormBuilder, NgForm } from '@angular/forms'
import { EmployeeService } from 'app/services/employee.service'
import { Router } from '@angular/router'
import { Employee } from 'app/shared/employee.model'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-employee',
  template: ` <form class="" [formGroup]="employeeForm" (ngSubmit)="saveEmployee()">
      <div class="form-control">
        <app-input
          #memberID
          name="memberID"
          label="Member ID"
          formControlName="memberID"
          placeholder="Member ID"
        ></app-input>
      </div>
      <div><button type="submit" class="">Save</button></div>
    </form>

    {{ employeeForm.value | json }}
`,
  styleUrls: ['./create-employee.component.scss'],
})

export class CreateEmployeeComponent implements OnInit {
  employeeForm: any
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private _employeeService: EmployeeService, private _router: Router) {}

  employee: Employee = {
    memberID: null,
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.employeeForm = this.fb.group({
      memberID: new FormControl(''),
    })

    this.employee = this.employeeForm.get('memberID').value
  }

  saveEmployee() {
    this._employeeService.save(this.employee)
    console.log(this.employeeForm.get('memberID').value)
    //   this._router.navigate(['employee-list'])
  }
}
```

**list-employee.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { Employee } from 'app/shared/employee.model'
import { EmployeeService } from 'app/services/employee.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-employees',
  template: `<div *ngFor="let employee of employees">
    <div class="">
      {{ employee.memberID }}
    </div>
  </div> `,
  styleUrls: ['./list-employees.component.scss'],
})
export class ListEmployeesComponent implements OnInit {
  employees: Employee[] = []
  constructor(private _employeeService: EmployeeService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.employees = this._employeeService.getEmployees()
  }
}
```

**employee.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { Employee } from 'app/shared/employee.model'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class EmployeeService {
  listEmployees: Employee[] = [{ memberID: '1' }, { memberID: '2' }]
  constructor() {}

  getEmployees(): Employee[] {
    return this.listEmployees
  }

  save(employee: Employee) {
    this.listEmployees.push(employee)
  }
}
```

Comment: At your saveEmployee() method, can you console log this._employeeService.getEmployees() to see if after your push it is being saved properly.

Comment: Also, are the CreateEmployeeComponent and ListEmployeesComponent under the same module?

Can you share your app.module?

Comment: Try adding constructor(private _employeeService: EmployeeService) {} to app.module.ts class and test it.